# Is there a way to call the pcfcross function on groups of marks?

Tags: spatstat

I'm using the pcfcross function to estimate the pair correlation functions (PCFs) between pairs of cell types, indicated by marks. I would now like to expand my analysis to include measuring the PCFs between cell types and groups of cell types. Is there a way to use the pcfcross function on a group of marks?

Alternatively, is there a way to change the marks of a group of marks to a singular mark?

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse several levels of a factor to a single level, using the `spatstat` function `mergeLevels`. This will group several types of points into a single type.

However, this may not give you any useful new information. The pair correlation function is a second-order summary, so the pair correlation for the grouped data can be calculated from the pair correlations for the un-grouped data. (See Chapter 7 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org)).